# Piggybacking - how close is too close? The case of Matthew 28:17

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I have an interest in the translation of [Matthew 28:17b](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2028%3A17&version=NASB;SBLGNT) and would like to hear the wisdom of BH.SE on it -

> 17 καὶ ἰδόντες αὐτὸν προσεκύνησαν, οἱ δὲ ἐδίστασαν. <sub>[SBLGNT]</sub>

There is an existing question on this verse, however: "[What exactly did the disciples doubt in Matt 28:17?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/17352/2215)"

I don't think my interest in this verse represents a duplicate, restricted as it is to the meaning of the Greek construction post-comma, and not about the nature of the Eleven's "doubt". This is obviously related, however, so I thought I would check the impression of the community before posting on Main.

Does my interest make for a viable independent question?

---

**Update**
This question was later posed: [Should Matthew 28:17b be understood in a "partitive" or "inclusive" sense?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/17412/3555)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, absolutely.

If a *proper* answer* that strictly but completely addresses the existing question being re-posted under the one you are going to ask would not resolve your question, then it is not a duplicate and you should go ahead and ask a new question.

<sub>* Note that such an answer might not have been posted yet but imagine one one based on the scope of the original question</sub>

Comment: Helpful diagnostic - thanks.